# How to sketch what would a 3-D graph parallel to an axis look like?

Tags: calculus, vectors, graphing-functions

Say the equation is $2x + 3y = 6$, why would it be parallel to z axis? What would it look like?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the equation does not depend on $z$, so it would take same values for any $z$ of your choice. Whatever the 2D graph of that looks like (it is actually a line with more traditional equation $y = 2 - 2x/3$) will get copied across the entire z-range, becoming a plane in 3D.